# How to replace using for() with all() in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a university activity that makes the following dataframe available:

```
      import pandas as pd
      from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
      from fuzzywuzzy import process

      df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0,1,2,3],
                          'name_city': ['RIO DE JANEIRO', 'SAO PAULO', 
                                        'ITU', 'CURITIBA'],
                          'city':['RIO JANEIRO', 'SAOO PAULO', 
                                  'FLORIANOPOLIS', 'BELO HORIZONTE']})

      print(df1)

            id  name_city             city
            0   RIO DE JANEIRO     RIO JANEIRO
            1   SAO PAULO          SAOO PAULO
            2   ITU                FLORIANOPOLIS
            3   CURITIBA           BELO HORIZONTE
```

I need to assess what is the similarity between the names of cities. So I'm using the fuzzy library and I made the following code:

```
      for i in range(0, len(df1)):
         df1['value_fuzzy'].iloc[i] = fuzz.ratio(df1['name_city'].iloc[i], df1['city'].iloc[i]

      This code works perfectly, the output is as desired:

      print(df1)

           id   name_city           city               value_fuzzy
           0    RIO DE JANEIRO     RIO JANEIRO             88
           1    SAO PAULO          SAOO PAULO              95
           2    ITU                FLORIANOPOLIS           12
           3    CURITIBA           BELO HORIZONTE          27
```

However, I would like to replace the for. So I tried to use all() which I found this example: [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

```
        df1['value_fuzzy'] = fuzz.ratio(df1['name_city'].all(), df1['city'].all())
```

But this code with all() returns wrong output:

```
       id   name_city        city          value_fuzzy
       0    RIO DE JANEIRO  RIO JANEIRO     27
       1    SAO PAULO       SAOO PAULO      27
       2    ITU             FLORIANOPOLIS   27
       3    CURITIBA        BELO HORIZONTE  27
```

Is there another way to generate the desired output without using for()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `fuzz.ratio` this way directly, the function is not vectorial.
You need to pass it to `apply`:

```
df1['value_fuzzy'] = df1.apply(lambda r: fuzz.ratio(r['name_city'], r['city']), axis=1)
```

*NB. Note that whatever you do, unless the function is specifically rewritten to handle vectorial input, that won't improve efficiency*

output:

```
   id       name_city            city  value_fuzzy
0   0  RIO DE JANEIRO     RIO JANEIRO           88
1   1       SAO PAULO      SAOO PAULO           95
2   2             ITU   FLORIANOPOLIS           12
3   3        CURITIBA  BELO HORIZONTE           27
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly! I had a question: which is more efficient: lambda or for?

Comment: In most cases if you can use a traditional `for` structure to deal with a dataframe column or line, you could do the same using `list comprehension` and comprehension is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1['value_fuzzy'] = df1.apply(lambda row : fuzz.ratio(row['name_city'],
                     row['city']), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it with list comprehension:

```
df1['value_fuzzy'] = [fuzz.ratio(df1['name_city'][i],df1['city'][i]) for i in range(len(df1.index))]
```

Output:

```
df1

   id        name_city            city  value_fuzzy
0   0   RIO DE JANEIRO     RIO JANEIRO           88
1   1        SAO PAULO      SAOO PAULO           95
2   2              ITU   FLORIANOPOLIS           12
3   3         CURITIBA  BELO HORIZONTE           27
```